# TypeError: objF.concat is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, ecmascript-6

I'm using a promise in NodeJS to execute a query, it returns an array, when I try to concatenate the first array with the second one, it returns the following error

> TypeError: objF.concat is not a function
>
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

**Code**

```
var objF = {
  album: []
};

for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
  if (response.data[i].name !== 'Untitled Album') {
    objF.album.push({
      id: response.data[i].id,
      name: response.data[i].name
    });
  }
}

var albumPromise = searchAlbumNext(next);

albumPromise.then(function(result) {
  var r = result;
  var union = objF.concat(r);
  res.status(200).send(union);
}, function(err) {
  res.status(400).send(err);
})
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is `objF`? It's not present in the code you've posted except for the `concat` line

Comment: What is `objF` ? [mcve] please...

Comment: check typeof objF. it does not seems to be array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue with `concat` is caused because `concat` is an array method, and `objF` is an object. I believe you want to do `objF.albums.concat`:

```
var union = objF.albums.concat(r);
```